# Do I need to have a company to create a website that collects users' personal info

Tags: legal, privacy

I want to build a website (or more like a personal project) that collects users' personal info (eg. email address). Is there any legal issue for that? I think I do need something like Privacy Policy, but do I need to have a company for the website?

Comment: What country are you in? Different countries have different laws.

Comment: I am in Canada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending of the personal info you want to collect. If you want a Name/e-mails for example, for a subscribers list or something like that - you are good to go without company. Of course you must have the right Privacy Policy and you shouldn't misuse the collected information. For certain types of PII however you'll need not only a company, but certifications too.

Comment: Thanks. Basically, Email / Password for them to log in. Andprobably username, gender. That's it.

Comment: You don't need to have a company for this, for sure. Still - make sure the password is encrypted in some way, and don't forget the Privacy Policy!